# Using value field in a dictionary as a key to split out into multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a Python Dictionary that currently looks like this:

```
A = {'Date':['2017-03-10','2017-03-10','2017-03-10','2017-03-10','2017-03-13','2017-03-13','2017-03-13','2017-03-13'],'Type':['One','Two','Three','Four','One','Two','Three','Four'],'Value':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]}
print A
```

I would like to create a top level dictionary such as each unique value in Type becomes part of the key itself.

Such that in this example, my top dictionary will have four dictionaries in it, one with the keys (A,One), the next one with keys (A,Two), next one with (A,Three) and the last one with (A,Four). The values inside those individual dicts will be be filtered accordingly. Thus the first underlying dict will only have values where the Type is 'One' and so on.

The top level dictionary will then be the combination of these four unique dictionaries. Any idea how I can arrive at this?

Comment: can you add the expected output for the input you provided? that would be a nice addition to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict

A = {'Date':['2017-03-10','2017-03-10','2017-03-10','2017-03-10','2017-03-13','2017-03-13','2017-03-13','2017-03-13'],'Type':['One','Two','Three','Four','One','Two','Three','Four'],'Value':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]}

B=defaultdict(list)
# group by index in the individual lists [ ( D[0], T[0], V[0]), ...]
for (d,t,v) in zip(A["Date"],A["Type"],A["Value"]):
    # each group (D[0],T[0],V[0]) 
    # Create dict B["A" + {"One"}]
    #                    insert in dict B["AOne"][{Date}] = {Value} 
    B["A"+t].append({d:v}) 

print(dict(B))
>>> {'AFour': [{'2017-03-10': 1}, {'2017-03-13': 1}], 'AOne': [{'2017-03-10': 1}, {'2017-03-13': 1}], 'ATwo': [{'2017-03-10': 1}, {'2017-03-13': 1}], 'AThree': [{'2017-03-10': 1}, {'2017-03-13': 1}]}
```

Something like that ?

Ideone test : http://ideone.com/e.js/5x2xs6